# Why must a virtual image be secured

Tags: virtualization

Virtual machines and their disk images are simply files residing somewhere. So I supposed this means that, for example, a stopped VM is potentially accessible on a file system. What could an attacker learn from the virtual image that might undermine  security - especially given that cloud technologies are built on VMs

Comment: Ask yourself what an attack can do with an exact copy of your computer or server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An attacker that grabs a disk image can take a lot of things:

- credentials
- source code
- database data
- configuration files
- log files
- application files
- passwords

It can make a copy of the disk image, start it somewhere, and have a deep understanding of everything inside, and that simplifies the process of finding vulnerabilities.

Extensive data leakage would be the result, and it's as bad as it can get.

Comment: I'm surprised passwords are stored in there? What type of passwords are we talking about and why on earth would they be there?

Comment: @Beginner A virtual machine is just an operating system. The operating system you are using right now is storing passwords.

Comment: @beginner, a VM image is basically a virtual hard drive, so whatever your server/computer has on it, so does the image file. Heck, a lot of backup software even gives the ability to boot into a VM of the backup.

Comment: @Beginner Passwords for database access, passwords for any proxy, OS user passwords, application passwords...

Comment: Thanks folks. I don’t think I appreciated the gravity of risk posed by a stolen VM snapshot. If I was a cloud customer I think I’d be very uncomfortable about having little control over it (in PaaS and SaaS, and would want strong controls in IaaS)